# Abaqus python script that will convert temperature in my .txt file

Tags: python, temperature, abaqus

I have a python script that extracts the temperature from my odb file however I want it to convert the temperature output from degrees F to degrees C. We input everything as english units put then our customers want things in the degrees C. How can I modify the following script to automatically convert my output to degrees C?

```
from odbAccess import *
import sys

# Open output file for writing
outputFile = open('OutputFileName.txt','w')

# Define odb file names
odbNameList = ('JobName.odb',)

# Define instance name and set name
instanceNameList = ('INSTANCE-1','INSTANCE-2',)
setName = 'SET-1'

# Process odb files
for odbName in odbNameList:

# Open file for reading
    odb = openOdb(path=odbName)

# Process steps
    for stepName in odb.steps.keys():

# Get field output objects for variables TEMPERATURE and ELEMENT VOLUME
        temperatureField = odb.steps[stepName].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['NT11']
        for instanceName in instanceNameList:               
            setData = odb.rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].nodeSets[setName]

            tempField = temperatureField.getSubset(region=setData, position=NODAL)
            tempValues = tempField.values

            tmax = 0
            for v in tempValues:
                if v.data > tmax:
                    tmax = v.data

            outputFile.write('%s %s %s %6.3f\n' % (odbName, stepName, instanceName, tmax))

# Close odb file
    odb.close()

# Close output file
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, simply identify which variable represents the temperature in Fahrenheit.  That value is `tmax`.  Converting that value to Celsius requires a simple calculation as demonstrated below.

```
if v.data > tmax:
    tmax = v.data
    tmax_celsius = (tmax-32)/1.8
```

Comment: Perfect!!! that did exactly what I wanted it too. I just changed one other thing in the outputFile.write step. I changed tmax to tmax_celsius.

Comment: @haledaco  Glad it worked.  Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are writing just the max temperature of every instance. You just need to work on `tmax` after you find it.

To convert Farenheit to Celsius use this formula:

```
C = (F-32)*(5/9)
```

So:

```
def Celsius(F):
    C = (F-32)*(5/9)
    return C

 temperatureField = odb.steps[stepName].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['NT11']
 for instanceName in instanceNameList:               
     setData = odb.rootAssembly.instances[instanceName].nodeSets[setName]

     tempField = temperatureField.getSubset(region=setData, position=NODAL)
     tempValues = tempField.values

     tmax = 0
     for v in tempValues:
        if Celsius(v.data) > tmax:
            tmax = v.data

     outputFile.write('%s %s %s %6.3f\n' % (odbName, stepName, instanceName, tmax))
```

Comment: In Python 2, Be-careful when dividing by 1 integer with another integer. It will return a integer and not a float.  In Python 2,  5/9 = 0.  Instead do this:   5.0/9 = 0.5555